# Include rows of NaN in matrix at predetermined row numbers.

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

Initially, I have

```
Matrix A= 
[ 1   2   3
  4 255   6
NaN NaN NaN
  7   8   9
 10  11  12
NaN NaN NaN 
10    9  11 ];
```

I find out the row numbers which are all NaN.

```
Row_NaN_MatA = [3 6];
```

After eliminating these rows, I am left with:

```
Matrix B1 = 
[ 1   2   3
  4 255   6
  7   8   9
 10  11  12
 10    9  11 ];
```

After applying a filter, I make the second row of Matrix B = NaN NaN NaN. Therefore

```
Matrix B2 = 
[ 1   2   3
NaN NaN NaN 
  7   8   9
 10  11  12
 10   9  11 ];
```

Now, the question is, after all these processing, I want to get the initial matrix back, but with all the deleted elements as NaN. So the required output I want is:

```
Output Matrix=
[ 1   2   3
NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN
  7   8   9
 10  11  12
NaN NaN NaN 
10    9  11 ];
```

I know the dimensions of output I want (= initial *Matrix A* dimensions), and the row numbers which should be NaN (= *Row_NaN_MatA*) . The rest of the rows should be equal to rows of *Matrix B2*.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) to get the row IDs that were not part of `Row_NaN_MatA` by `setdiff-ing` `Row_NaN_MatA` with the a 1D array of indices for the entire row extent of `A`, like so  -

```
output = A
output(setdiff(1:size(A,1),Row_NaN_MatA),:) = B2
```

You can also use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for the same effect -

```
output(~ismember(1:size(A,1),Row_NaN_MatA),:) = B2
```

Or use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) there -

```
output(all(bsxfun(@ne,Row_NaN_MatA(:),1:size(A,1))),:) = B2
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3
     4   255     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
   NaN   NaN   NaN
    10     9    11
>> B1
B1 =
     1     2     3
     4   255     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    10     9    11
>> B2
B2 =
     1     2     3
   NaN   NaN   NaN
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    10     9    11
>> output
output =
     1     2     3
   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
   NaN   NaN   NaN
    10     9    11
```